# How do I get the "Redirect After Login" URL programatically?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've been writing a module that replaces the registration form in DNN to work more with our system.  I've been trying to figure out how to programatically get the URL that is specified on the Admin Settings page for the "Redirect After Login" field.  Under the PortalSettings object, I've been able to find a lot of different TabID properties, but none of them appear to be for this field.  I believe the field I am looking for to be in a different class, but I know not where.  Has anyone run into this field or know better where I can look?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, I found the answer very soon after posting.

I found "Redirect_AfterRegistration" in the PortalSettings table which can be accessed via the PortalController.GetPortalSettingsDictionary(PortalId) method.  This alone is not enough, since this value may be -1 and thus redirect you back to the same page (typically the registration page).  There exists code in \DesktopModules\Admin\Security\Register.ascx.cs which provides functionality for redirection after registering.  In 7.1.x this code has a bug, but with some modification I came up with this:

```
    public string RedirectAfterRegisterUrl
    {
        get
        {
            const string key = "Redirect_AfterRegistration";
            const string returnUrlKey = "returnurl";
            var url = "";
            var settings = DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.GetPortalSettingsDictionary(PortalId);


            if (settings.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var tabId = Convert.ToInt32(settings[key]);
                if (tabId > 0)
                {
                    url = DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(tabId);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString[returnUrlKey] != null)
                    {
                        url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString[returnUrlKey]);
                        if (url.Contains("//"))
                            url = "";

                        if (url.Contains("?returnurl")) 
                        { 
                            string baseURL = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?returnurl", StringComparison.Ordinal)); 
                            string returnURL = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("?returnurl", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 11); 
                            url = string.Concat(baseURL, "?returnurl", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnURL)); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return url;
        }
    }
```

My tests have shown that this redirects me to the specified Redirect After Registration page.  I hope this solutions helps others as well!